# If one checkbox is checked,check And disable other checkbox Angular

Tags: typescript, checkbox, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

When key1 checkbox is checked, I want to check and disable key2 checkbox

HTMLcode

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" formControlName="key1" id="key1" (click)="key1Click()">
            <label for="key1" class="form-check-label">Key 1</label>
            <input class="form-check-input" formControlName="key2" type="checkbox" id="key2">
            <label for="key2" class="form-check-label">Key 2</label>
```

Typescript code for checkbox

```
keyClick() {

let x = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("key1");
let y = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("key2");
if (x.checked) {
  y.checked = true;
  y.disabled = true;
}
else {
  y.checked = false;
  y.disabled = false;
}
```

}

By using this code key2 checkbox is checked and disabled.
But the boolean value of key2 checkbox remains false.
Any suggestions on how can I change the boolean value of key2 checkbox to true when I click key1 checkbox
I am using Angular 8 and its reactive forms module.I am new to angular.

Comment: Do not never ever manipulate DOM elements directly with Angular. I don't know what you really want to achieve, but don't you think that radio buttons could be a better choice?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Whenever key1 checkbox is clicked  I want to check (boolean value = true) and disable key2 checkbox . Is there any way I can achieve that?

Comment: if you want only one checkbox to be checked at a time, go for radio buttons, instead of using checkboxes.

Comment: @AbhishekTewari I want them both checked when I click key1 checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subscribe to the `valueChanges` observable of the first checkbox,i.e., `key1`.

Demo snippet:

```
this.formName.get("key1").valueChanges.subscribe(val=>{
    if(val)
    //enable the second checkbox
    else 
    //disable the second checkbox
});
```

where **formName** is the name of your reactive form.
Also don't forget to unsubscribe to this observable on component destroy.

Comment: I will check this method. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Kindly upvote and accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: @Pratik Happy to help. :)
Kindly upvote the answer.